# Scrapy loading not loading all info into postgres. Why?

Tags: python, postgresql, scrapy

I'm trying to take the information I collected using scrapy and display it in postgres. Everything works except it only loads the first item in the first row in my data table.

I think there's a loop that is needed in the def parse but I am not sure what to do. I've tried a few different loops.

quotes_spider.py

```
import scrapy
from ..items import TutorialItem

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = [
        'https://campustechnology.com/articles/list/news.aspx'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        items = TutorialItem()

        title = response.css('.title a::text').extract()
        author = response.css('.summary::text').extract()
        date = response.css('.nodate::text').extract()
        urls = response.css('.title a').xpath("@href").extract()

        items["title"] = title
        items["author"] = author
        items["date"] = date
        items["urls"] = urls
        yield items
```

pipelines.py

```
import psycopg2


class TutorialPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
            "host=pellefant.db.elephantsql.com dbname=x user=x 
             password=x"
        )
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.cur.execute("drop table if exists quotes_tb;")
        self.cur.execute('''
             create table quotes_tb(
               title varchar(255),
               author varchar(255),
               date varchar(255),
               urls varchar(255)
               )
        ''')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        return item

    def store_db(self, item):
        self.cur.execute('''insert INTO quotes_tb (title, author, date, 
                          urls) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)''', (
            item["title"][0],
            item["author"][0],
            item["date"][0],
            item["urls"][0]
        ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

I'm expecting to see my database have a list of all the information separated by rows. Not just the first info collected and one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put only one row because you put  `item["title"][0]`, (etc.) but there can be also `item["title"][1]` and `item["title"][2]`, etc.

---

You can  use `for`-loop with `zip()` to group elements and insert every row separatelly

```
for row in zip(item["title"], item["author"], item["date"], item["urls"]):
     self.cur.execute('''insert INTO quotes_tb (title, author, date, urls) 
                           VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)''', row )
```

or first create all rows and later use only one query with `execute_values()`

```
all_rows = list( zip(item["title"], item["author"], item["date"], item["urls"]) )

self.cur.execute_values('''insert INTO quotes_tb (title, author, date, urls) 
                           VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)''',  all_rows)
```